# How to get rid of PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in X on line 123

Tags: php, e-notices

I just discovered that I have thousands of these errors, coming from two of the same files.

I have removed a lot of errors by using the `isset`, but I can´t figure out how to remove the last two errors. Maybe you guys can help me.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTPS on /xxx/xxx/xxx.php on line 123
```

Code from the first PHP file that generates the error:

```
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
return $pageURL;
}
```

More exactly this line:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
```

And

```
if (isset($tag)) {
$tag = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['tag'], ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use isset there, too?

Comment: I´ve tried setting $tag to NULL if its not set, but it does not help

Comment: Where are you initially setting `$tag`? The if statement you've included is checking to see if it's already set, then assigning a value to it - do you maybe mean to do `if (isset($_REQUEST['tag']))` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
```

to:

```
if (array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
```

[array_key_exists](http://php.net/array_key_exists) returns a boolean. Since I check it first and use && the if statement will exit before checking the value of $_SERVER["HTTPS"] if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Glad to hear it fixed it for you.

Comment: It also fixes a common problem with the wordpress contact form 7 multistep plugin. Thanks.